# How to retrieve the newest(current) time value specificd by DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on jpa entity's property?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a JPA entity, which contains two column, the `createdTime` and `modifiedTime`. I'd like to use MySQL's `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` feature to generate the proper time value for this two column, so i write my entity class like:

```java
@Entity
public class Blog {
    // ...

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_time", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = false,
        columnDefinition = "datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date createdTime;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "modified_time", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = false,
        columnDefinition = "datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date modifiedTime;
}
```

Then i do some experiment on my application, when i check the database, the value of this two column in the database is updated properly.

However, when i check the java entity return by `BlogRepository::save`, the value of this two column is not the newest value. For example, when i insert a new `Blog` entity, i get null for this two properties on the `BlogRepository::save` return value.

I've read some post like https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237110/8510613, understand that if i mark the column as `updatable = false`, this situation will happen. So how should i fix this? Simply remove the `updatable = false`/`insertable = false` seems have no help, but will trigger the column's not null constraint violation. But if i remove the not null constraint on this two column, the value of this two column are just simply null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [@Generated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-Generated) annotation in this case.

> 2.3.18. Generated properties
>
> Generated properties are properties that have their values generated by the database. Typically, Hibernate applications needed to refresh objects that contain any properties for which the database was generating values. **Marking properties as generated, however, lets the application delegate this responsibility to Hibernate.** When Hibernate issues an SQL INSERT or UPDATE for an entity that has defined generated properties, it immediately issues a select to retrieve the generated values.

So, you should correct your mapping something like this:

```java
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(name = "created_time", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = false,
        columnDefinition = "datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Date createdTime;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
@Column(name = "modified_time", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = false,
        columnDefinition = "datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Date modifiedTime;
```

Comment: Might this cause some performance problem? Since "When Hibernate issues an SQL INSERT or UPDATE for an entity that has defined generated properties, it immediately issues a select to retrieve the generate values".

Comment: Theoretically yes, but it is difficult to say something for sure without measurement for your particular use case.