# Handling time stamping in child tables

Tags: java, spring, jpa

We are learning JPA to migrate to Spring and we are struggling with table relationships (OneToMany and ManyToMany) in where the tables require a time stamp. Unfortunately our existing legacy tables use *ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant().toEpochMilli()* in code to store the time stamps in BIGINT columns. Here is a simplified example *one-to-many* relationship between the *company* and *contact* tables:

```
create table contact
(
    id          bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    company_id  bigint unsigned not null,
    name        varchar(255)    not null,
    disabled_at bigint          null,
    created_at  bigint          not null,
    modified_at bigint          not null,
    constraint contact_uidx01
        unique (company_id, name),
    constraint contact_fk01
        foreign key (company_id) references company (id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade,
);
```

If we define the @OneToMany in the *Company* and *Contact* models/entities then how do we update the *created_at* (for new records) and *modified_at* columns in code?

We have the *addContact()* in the *company* model/entity like so:

```
public void addContact( Contact contact )
{
  this.contactList.add( contact );
  contact.setCompany( this );
  /* Update time stamps here? Doesn't make sense! */
}
```

Obviously when we try to persist this using our *CompanyRepository* class we receive the *"created_at" and "modified_at" cannot be NULL* SQL error(s) for our *contact* table.

```
  public boolean save( Company company )
  {
    /* Set time stamps */
    Long timeStamp = ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    company.setModifiedAt( timeStamp ); // always set

    if ( company.getCreatedAt() == null )
    {
      company.setCreatedAt( timeStamp );
    }

    try
    {
      entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
      entityManager.persist( company );
      entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
      return true;
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
  }
```

None of the JPA books/videos we are studying seem to cover time stamping very well. They gloss over it and/or crutch it off to the database to perform. That's not really ideal and it won't work in our environment.

We only want to set/update the *created_at* and *modified_at* column at the moment the records are persisted (saved) to the database. The above example *save()* works fine for the *company* table but when JPA is handling the child tables it's not so obvious.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [tag:spring-data-jpa]?? -> [tag:hibernate]!(?) -> `@Pre`-`update`/`persist`! better: do it in sql! ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6597588/592355))

Comment: Not sure if I understood it correctly, but check `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` annotations that can be used at entity level to skip providing of date time for saving.

Answer (score 0):

This link provides a very good explanation and example of how to implement time-stamping (Auditing) with JPA:

[How to audit entity modifications using the JPA @EntityListeners,
@Embedded, and @Embeddable annotations](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-audit-entity-modifications-using-the-jpa-entitylisteners-embedded-and-embeddable-annotations/)